# From what files are the .fmt files generated?

Tags: format-files

I am trying to dig into the inner workings of LaTeX and to see where basic macros such as `\{` are defined. `texdef` gives nothing useful (saying that it is defined by LaTeX) and the .fmt files, being binary files, are obviously generated from something. How are the .fmt files generated, and where can I get the files from which they are made?

Comment: `latex.ltx` in `tex/latex/base/`.

Comment: @cfr You are correct. `\{` and friends are defined with `DeclareRobustCommand` which I had forgotten to search for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `.fmt` file is a "format" file that is generated by the program `inittex`.  It loads a standard `.tex` file and in a sense "compiles" it using `inittex`'s `dump` command which creates a binary representation of this "compiled" `.tex` file.

The original purpose of format files was to speed the loading of such tex files.  Bechtolsheim, in "TeX in Practice, Vol II", states that loading the `plain.tex` file would take 80 seconds on a VAX 11/780 under BSD UNIX 4.2, while loading `plain.fmt` took only 10 seconds.

Obviously, today's machines are so much faster that the difference probably isn't discernible.  Still, for reasons of efficiency, `.fmt` files might as well be used with common formats such as plain, csplain, LaTeX, etc.

The standard way of loading an `.fmt` file is something like `tex --fmt=pdfcsplain ...`, but that can be embedded inside a command, shell script or other executable.  (I'm sure `latex` is one of those.)